# Safari crashes instantly when trying to debug iPad Simulator app

Tags: ipad, safari, ios-simulator

I realize that this is a long-shot... but I'm looking for tips or advice on how to prevent or debug this issue.

If I start my app in the iPad simulator (webapp using phonegap), then start Safari and select Develope->iPad Simulator->index.html  - Safari immediately crashes.  The odd thing is that I'm one of several developers working on this app... and we all have seemingly identical setups - yet this doesn't happen for them.  They are able to debug in Safari as expected.  I should also mention that the app itself works great in the simulator.

Software involved:
Xcode 4.6.2
Safari 6.0.5
Running simulator for iPad 6.1

Again, I realize that this isn't much to go on.  Hoping someone might be able to point me in the right direction to figure it out.

Comment: This is a long shot too but have you tried clearing the cache in Safari? And do you see the same behaviour when using a real device?

Comment: Only use the [tag:xcode] tag for questions about the IDE itself. Thanks!

Comment: @Robert - yes I've tried clearing the cache in safari.  I've also disabled extensions in hopes a third party extension might be to blame.

Comment: SOLVED!  On a whim I tried removing:
 `~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/[app-specific-directory]` 
and that has solved the issue.  I didn't expect this, given that it seemed to be safari related - but it worked.

Answer (score 4):

SOLVED!

On a whim I blew away the directory for the app in:
~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/6.1/Applications/

and Voila - debugging in Safari works again - doesn't just crash-on-load!

Comment: You essentially reset your simulator. Not sure if this was a solution - Seems like there was some bad data in there that was causing a crash. The problem might occur in the future if the data were to become corrupt again.

Comment: @Sid - that is exactly what I suspect as well (corrupted data).  What I find odd, however, is that the app itself was running perfectly in the simulator - and passing our extensive suite of unit and functional tests.  I wouldn't expect that Safari itself would store anything in that directory - so I'm at a loss as to what was corrupt and causing the issues.

Comment: Each app has caches to themselves, and deleting an app (which is essentially what you did) is a way to delete any lingering web-related stuff.

Comment: Had the same issue of Safari crashing. Fixed it.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those people finding this with a more recent version of Mac OS and Xcode/iOS Simulator, this fix worked for me as well:

Mac OS version: 10.12.6
iOS Simulator version: 10.0

1. Open up iOS Simulator.
2. On the menu bar go to Hardware > Erase All Content and Settings > Reset.
3. Restart your Mac

Should be back up and running after that.